# python unable to extract protocol from ethernet frame 'struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 20 bytes'

Tags: python, udp, ethernet

I m using python to extract a procol(udp,tcp) from an ip datagram.
But my problem is to unpack the data I get from ethernet frame.
I use this function for that

```
def ipv4_head(data):
 version_h = data[0]
 version = version_h >> 4
 header_length = (version_h & 15) * 4
 ttl, proto, src, target = struct.unpack('! 8x B B 2x 4s 4s', raw_data[:20])
 data = raw_data[header_length:]
 return version, header_length, ttl, proto, src, target, data
```

My problem is this line '''

> struct.unpack('! 8x B B 2x 4s 4s', raw_data[:20])

I have an error

> struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 20 bytes

I tried a many thinks, this one too give the same result

> struct.unpack("!BBHHHBBH4s4s", raw_data)

with an other function but is still the same

```
def ipv4_head(raw_data):
  store=struct.unpack("!BBHHHBBH4s4s", raw_data)
  src_ip=socket.inet_ntoa(store[8])
  dst_ip=socket.inet_ntoa(store[9])
  protocol=store[6]

  return src_ip,dst_ip, protocol
```

But it's the same, I use python 3.

I'm interested too, to bypass the struct.unpack by using another method.
A many days I'm strugling with this error but I found nothing in internet.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that your buffer (the second argument) is not 20 bytes in length.

Can you try `print(len(raw_data[:20]))`?  If `raw_data` is shorter than 20 bytes, your expression won't be long enough.